# C++ array did not change though passed by reference

Tags: c++

I have the following code for Quick Sort.
Though the array is being passed by reference in both the functions- split and quicksort, I could not understand why the changed array is not shown in result. In some book, I saw that the quicksort prototype was defined inside main function. But that also did not worked.
Also tell is it allowed to define prototype of another function inside main.

```
#include <iostream>
void quicksort(int *,int,int);
int split(int *,int,int);    
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"\n Enter the 10 elements : ";
int n=10;
int a[10];    
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
cin>>a[i];
}    

    quicksort(a,0,9);
    cout<<"\nThe sorted array is: ";
    for(int c=0;c<10;c++)
    {
        cout<<a[c]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
void quicksort(int arr[],int lower,int upper)
{
int i;
    if(upper<lower)
    {
        i=split(arr,lower,upper);
        quicksort(arr,lower,i-1);
        quicksort(arr,i+1,upper);
    }
}
int split(int arr[],int lower, int upper)
{
    int i,a,b,temp;
    a=lower+1;
    b=upper;
    i=arr[lower];
    while(b>=a)
    {
        while(arr[a]<i)
            a++;
        while(arr[b]>i)
            b++;
        if(b>a)
        {
            temp=arr[a];
            arr[a]=arr[b];
            arr[b]=temp;
        }
    }

    temp=arr[lower];
    arr[lower]=arr[b];
    arr[b]=temp;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The array is *not* passed by reference in your code.

Comment: Please tell how to modify.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: True, but the effect is the same as if it were.

Comment: The first thing I would try (well, the second, after fixing the code's indentation) is to confirm that the assignments to the array elements in `split` are actually executed, either by adding temporary print statements or by running the program in a debugger. Once you find that the code never reaches that point, you can look at the logic of your algorithm rather than assuming that pass-by-reference (or rather pass-by-implicit-pointer-value) isn't working properly.

Comment: Hmm, I ran your code. The `upper < lower` condition is wrong. Should be `lower < upper`. After I fixed it it was crashing elsewhere in split. You should debug it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another mistake:

```
    while(arr[b]>i)
        b++;
```

should be

```
    while(arr[b]>i)
        b--;
```

One more mistake:

```
  while(arr[a]<i)
    a++;
```

should be:

```
  while(arr[a]<=i)
    a++;
```

verdict: buggy algorithm implementation

Answer (score 4):

Here's the mistake:

```
if(upper<lower)
```

Since `upper` is initially bigger than `lower`, the `quicksort` function terminates immediately. The comparison should be the other way around. (Except that the program segfaults when I try that, but that's a different problem.)

Comment: How can it be, I am simply checking whether the array contains more than one element.You tell me how should it be written.

Comment: @AbhishekJain your first call to quicksort will check if 9 < 0, and will not do anything else.

Comment: @AbishekJain You probably want to flip the comparison. Looks like you want to make sure that upper is greater than lower as that would effectively check if the array contains at least one element.

Comment: @larsmans when I change the comparison condition,segfault occurs.How to rectify it?

Comment: @AbhishekJain: I noticed that, but I'm not going to debug your homework for you.